# auto run application that forced to run as administrator

Tags: c#, setup.exe

i build a windows form setup application(.exe) and forced that run as administrator.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

i want to auto run this app when windows was booted. To do this I added the following code to my program.

```
RegistryKey autoRun = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
autoRun.SetValue("my app name", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

now my problam is **when i remove limit of run as administrator**, my app auto run when windows was booted. but **when my app forced to run as administrator**, my app con't auto run.
how can i solved this problam?
thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/929225/how-to-run-a-program-as-an-administrator-at-startup-on-windows-10

Comment: Use Windows Scheduler to set up the task which will run on logon/boot. Sample .NET wrapper: https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler/wiki/TaskSecurity